# How to get json and display it by user id

Tags: json, angular

I want to display the data of the selected user in angular 2. I make a service to get the data from API

```
   getUserById(id: string): Promise<User> {   
   const url ='api/user/${id}';   
   return this.httpClient.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json() as User)
    .catch(this.handleError);   }
```

and this is my controller

```
 user: User;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    userService.getUserById('45835708-f55a-40fb-878f-33b9c920e196')
    .then(hasil => this.user = hasil)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

and here is my template

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">FULL NAME</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input  class="form-control"  type="text" value="" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">USER NAME</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control"  type="text" value="" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">PASSWORD</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control"  type="password" value="" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">DATE OF BIRTH</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control"  type="text" value="" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
```

How to display the json to my template? Do I make correct service and controller?

Comment: How does your JSON response look like? Have you made sure `this.user` has values?

Comment: {
  "id" : "45835708-f55a-40fb-878f-33b9c920e196",
  "fullName" : "Syahrul P Utomo",
  "userName" : "syahrul",
  "password" : "123456",
  "dob" : "1991-01-11",
  "email" : "irull@yahoo.com",
  "phone" : "0876757575"
}

Comment: this.user is still empty man

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use template driven forms or reactive driven forms.

`this.user` object can be a model to that form, and when you input something into html input elements, object will update automatically:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">FULL NAME</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input  class="form-control"  type="text" value="" [(ngModel)]="user.fullName" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">USER NAME</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control"  type="text" value="" [(ngModel)]="user.username" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">PASSWORD</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control"  type="password" value="" [(ngModel)]="user.password" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">DATE OF BIRTH</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control"  type="date" value="" [(ngModel)]="user.dateOfBirth" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
```

If you want to add some validator, you should go with Reactive forms:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html

The principle here is to create a form group and define individual properties with their initial values and validator.

Comment: Can you create a sample code on plunker and share it here.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have `FormsModule` imported in your module. Then... remember to use `ngModel` to bind the `user` to the form.

But, forms do not care about `ngModel` unless there is also a `name` attribute on each field:

```html
<input  class="form-control" name="fullName" [ngModel]="user.fullName">
```

**OR**

`ngModelOptions` in each field:

```html
<input  class="form-control" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [ngModel]="user.fullName">
```

Here's a demo for you with usage of the `name` attribute:

### **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XtWmDWdSsPRa4U2mCNiy?p=preview)**

Comment: here is my service

Comment: getUserById(id: string): Promise<User> {
  const url = 'api/user/${id}';
  return this.httpClient.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(hasil => hasil.json() as User)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

Comment: and this is user.component.ts

Comment: constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    userService.getUserById('e9776c74-b1d6-4ba2-a35e-faa05af7c86f')
    .then(hasil => this.user = hasil)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

Comment: Unexpected end of json

Comment: seems not to be valid json, or then you are getting no response at all. Could you check the network tab and paste the response? :)

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:4200/user/view
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:4200

Comment: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
view-user.component.ts:24Terjadi error : Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: I mean, paste the response from the tab `response`, which can be found in the network tab :)

Comment: Like so: http://imgur.com/a/kYbrT I suspect you are not getting values in your response, then you need to check that, probably nothing wrong with angular code.